# PDF to text conversion Error (Python, PyPDF2)

Tags: python, pdf, text, data-cleaning, pypdf

I'm working on text cleanup for nlp and am currently running into issues with my pdf to text conversion process. I am using PyPdf2. First, I crop header and footers, then convert those pdfs to text and only then clean them. I'm working with academic journals and am getting mixed results. my first batch of pdfs was cropped/ converted/ cleaned without issue. My next batch however is failing to convert properly. every couple of lines, a new line is ignored, and words get concatenated together. this concatenation is not something that can be fixed in the cleanup stage. I'm not sure why this happens for pdfs from one batch but not another.
here are the relevant code snippets

pdf_convertor is a function that takes 5 arguments. It converts a pdf file to a text file,
and (optionally) trims the header and footer
Parameters:

```
  pdf_path(string) = file path of pdf to be converted

  new_path(string) = file path of the text file that is created 

  h_f(string) = user inputs "y" if they want the header and footer trimmed, "n" otherwise

  l_b(int) = user inputs lower bound co-ordinates for footer cropping
  
  u_b(int) = user input upper bound co-ordinates for header cropping
```

Returns:

```
  none
```

```
def pdf_convertor(pdf_path, new_path, h_f, l_b, u_b):    
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)

    parts = []
    text_body = ""

    def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
        y = tm[5]
        if y > l_b and y < u_b:
            parts.append(text)

    for current_page in range(len(reader.pages)):
      page = reader.pages[current_page]
      if h_f == "y":
        page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor_body)
        text_body = "".join(parts)
      elif h_f == "n":
        text = page.extractText()
        parts.append(text)
        text_body = "".join(parts)
      else:
        print("please input y if you would like header/footer trimmed, else input n")
        return
    
    newfile = open(new_path, "w") 
    newfile.write(text_body)
    newfile.close()
```

```
files = Path(directory).glob('*')
i = 0
for file in files:
    pdf_convertor(file, new_path, 'y', 70, 700)

    with open(new_path, "r") as f:
        text = f.read()
        f.close()
    
    text = re.sub("\nReference((.|\n)*)"," ", text)
    #removes reference pages from pdf
    
    with open(path + str(i) +"result.txt", 'w') as p:
      p.write(text)
      p.close()
    i += 1
```

Comment: @K_J I'm doing this on google collab and am a little confused by what packages I need to install to make pdftotext work. I've tried importing pdftotext, pip installing poppler, etc. nothing doing so far. if you have any advice I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @K_J well after messing around with poppler for a bit, I got pdftotext imported, but I'm still having issues getting it to actually convert text. the best I can do is get the manpage to show up for it.                                                                                         
        pdf = !pdftotext -x 100 -y 100 file 
is how i'm calling it but either file isn't found (regardless of what I put in place of file) or if i dont include file, i get the man page

Comment: @K_J I got it to work and to strip headers and footers.  I am going to have to rely on your kindness one more time and ask. Any chance that you know how I would call this in a loop and pass it variable names. is the only option to write a script, and then to call the executable, or is it possible to do inside the program/function. Also, Thanks for the help! this so far seems to be a great bandaid fix for documents that wont work with PyPdf2